# Splitting an array based on values of another array

Tags: javascript, nlp

Let's say I have the word 'buddy'

the first array breaks the word up by syllables eg. `['bud','dy']`

the second array is by their phonogram breakup eg. `['b','u','dd',y']`

now my issue is the phonogram 'dd' should be 'd','d' because there is a syllable break there but I can't think of a efficient way to parse both array's and break the phonograms so that it is `['b','u','d','d',y']`

here are some other examples

word: **driveway**

syllables: `['drive','way']`

phonograms: `['d','r','i','ew','ay']`

should be: `['d','r','i','v','e','w','ay']`

word: **getting**

syllables: `['get','ting']`

phonograms: `['g','e','tt','i','ng']`

should be: `['g','e','t','t','i','ng']`

Any one know of a way I can do this?

Comment: This isn't about JavaScript actually. Should tag _natural language processing_, _nlp_, or something relative. Still it's an interesting question for JS guys like me.

Comment: `everyday` does not contain the syllables `['drive','way']`, you may want to clean up that example.  What are the inefficient ways you've come up with for parsing both arrays and breaking the phonograms?

Comment: it is because i'm trying to write a script to compare the two arrays and work out if they been to be split or not

Comment: @adamdc78 thanks didn't see that

Comment: Seems like it would work to first break on syllables, then break each syllable into phonograms. No? I mean there shouldn't every be a phonogram that spans two syllables, right?

Comment: @sixfingeredman yeh i could give that a try although syllables are manually inputted whereas phonograms are generated so i would need to delay the generation of the phonograms until the users had split the words

Comment: If you had the phonograms first, you could take the original word, split it into syllables, then walk across each letter in both arrays, and when you get to a syllable break that happens in the middle of a phonogram, you could manually split it at that point, introducing the new parts into the phonogram array.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this [pseudocode]

```
 given i = 0, word = ""
 for phono in phonograms        //loop over all phonograms
      word += phonograms[phono] //and try to assemble the current syllable
      if word === syllable[i]                   //we may have found a sullable
           i++
           word = ""
           continue
      if not the syllable[i] starts with word   //if not syllable starts with word, 
                                                //then we have a phono that 
                                                //breaks our rules
           phonos = phonograms[phono].split("") //so let's split that into characters
           for j in phonos
                phonograms.splice(phono++, 0, phonos[j]) //and insert to 
                                                         //the list of phonograms
           i++
```